# Grep in Unix + like in SQL + groupby in SQL

Tags: linux, unix, search, awk, grep

What I have in the file is

```
112}2014-03-02}ABC
112}2014-02-02}ABC
112}}ABC
112}2014-03-02}ABC
112}2013-03-02}ABC
112}2013-02-02}ABC
112}2013-03-02}ABC
```

I need to grep and see something like this as a output and looking for a one liner (grep preferred)

```
2014-03-02 2
2014-02-02 1
           1
2013-03-02 2
2013-02-02 1
```

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380817/best-way-to-simulate-group-by-from-bash) but it does not serve my purpose.

I also tried something like these but no luck

```
grep -ioh '2014' file.txt | sort | uniq -c
grep -ioh '2013' file.txt | sort | uniq -c
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `awk` may do:

```
awk -F\} '{a[$2]++} END {for (i in a) printf "%-10s %s\n",i,a[i]}' file
           1
2013-02-02 1
2014-02-02 1
2014-03-02 2
2013-03-02 2
```

Comment: +1 and I can accept this as a solution. Just out of curiosity. How to ignore blanks or any other data that is not of the date format

Comment: You can do: `awk -F\} '{a[$2]++} END {for (i in a) if (i~/^20/) printf "%-9s %s\n",i,a[i]}'`  To be more exact, use `(i~/^20[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]/)`

Comment: May be better to ignore the blanks in the main process instead of the `END`.

Comment: @fedorqui I do agree :)  `awk -F\} '$2~/^20[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]/ {a[$2]++} END {for (i in a) printf "%-10s %s\n",i,a[i]}'`

Answer (score 1):

Here how you could do it with `egrep`:

```
egrep -o '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}' file.txt | sort | uniq -c
```

Output:

```
1 2013-02-02
2 2013-03-02
1 2014-02-02
2 2014-03-02
```

#### Edit

To also count lines without a date on them, you can approach it similarly to @Jotnes answer:

```
grep -o '}[^}]*}' | tr -d '}' | sort | uniq -c
```

Output:

```
1 
1 2013-02-02
2 2013-03-02
1 2014-02-02
2 2014-03-02
```

Comment: This misses the `112}}ABC` (the blank one)

Comment: +1 and thanks for your response. You gave me the answer that I expected. But I give it to the fastest finger.

Comment: @Jotne: You are right. I have added an alternative that works with the given input. Thanks.