# Print a specific column on a condition using awk

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk

I have modified the output of `iostat -e` like this:

```
iostat -e | egrep -v  "errors|trn" | gawk -v name="`uname -n `" '{if($2 > 0 || $3 > 0) print name,$1}' | tr '\n' ' '  ' > ~/abd/diskcheck.out
```

I want to print the value of the second column in next columns where value of first column is repeated using `Linux` commands.

my sample file is:

```
$ cat diskcheck.out                                               
hxcsvc-a02 sd2
hxcslc-a01 sd23
hxcslc-a02 sd14
hxcslc-a02 sd17
hxcslc-a02 sd18
hxcslc-a02 sd19
hxcslc-a03 sd11
hxcslc-a07 sd3
hxcslc-a09 sd2
```

Expected Output:

```
hxcsvc-a02 sd2
hxcslc-a01 sd23
hxcslc-a02 sd14 sd17 sd18 sd19
hxcslc-a03 sd11
hxcslc-a07 sd3
hxcslc-a09 sd2
```

Comment: Since you are new here in SO, read through [How to ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: yes I am a newbie. please help me in resolving the above issue. Many thanks

Comment: SO is not a coding service! You should let us know with code, what you tried and how you failed.

Comment: i can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: [print column on a condition using awk](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=print+column+on+a+condition+using+awk&oq=print+column+on+a+condition+using+awk&aqs=chrome..69i57.6192j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), try browsing through examples and make an attempt of your own.

Comment: what i did first was that i want to stream down the output of iostat -e for my multiple nodes.

Comment: Make an attempt in solving the problem and post it as part of the question and let us know how you failed. Try with `awk`

Comment: @user7352907, Inian's point is not to add the iostat but to post your attempt at the current problem. Also why are you tying your hands down to use only `awk`?

Comment: Related solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2613073

Comment: @user7352907: I have added a detailed explanation along with the answer. Feel free to understand it and let us know if it solved your problem.

Comment: @user7352907: Don't forget to click on the small tick on the left of my answer to mark it accepted i.e. to mean the problem is resolved.

Comment: done! thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `awk` in a simpler way

```
awk 'BEGIN{delete hash;}{hash[$1]=hash[$1]FS$2}END{for (i in hash) print i, hash[i]}' file
hxcslc-a07  sd3
hxcslc-a09  sd2
hxcsvc-a02  sd2
hxcslc-a01  sd23
hxcslc-a02  sd14 sd17 sd18 sd19
hxcslc-a03  sd11
```

where `file` is your input file

```
$ cat file                                               
hxcsvc-a02 sd2
hxcslc-a01 sd23
hxcslc-a02 sd14
hxcslc-a02 sd17
hxcslc-a02 sd18
hxcslc-a02 sd19
hxcslc-a03 sd11
hxcslc-a07 sd3
hxcslc-a09 sd2
```

I will try to break-down the answer, since you are just using it,

- In general, `awk` processes lines one at a time and has a syntax `awk 'BEGIN{..}{..}END{..}'` where the instructions within `BEGIN` and `END` are executed before and after the completion of file processing in respective order.
- All your columns are white-space separated, `awk` by default splits input records by this de-limiter only. You can change this and output field-separation as you need with `FS` and `OFS` variables respectively.
- In your case, as per requirement am building a hash table with `$1` (which means 1st column delimited by space) as index and value as `$2`. Am appending the values per unique key with the already existing value.
- After all the lines are processed, in the `END` loop, am printing the unique index hashed along with its value.

If you want to run the above command in pipe-line with other commands, try with

```
<your-previous-command> | awk 'BEGIN{delete hash;}{hash[$1]=hash[$1]FS$2}END{for (i in hash) print i, hash[i]}'
```

For more detailed instructions on its usage, recommend some [`Awk tutorials`](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html).

Comment: The BEGIN section isn't doing anything useful., you could just remove it.