# powershell equivalent to group-object in bash/linux ?

Tags: linux, powershell

In Powershell, you can parse a csv file for example, and use the command group-objects to get basic stats such as the number of records for particular items etc..

I was wondering if there's a quick trick in bash to do roughly the same and group objects by a certain field ? (I am thinking it could be possible using awk, but I've not find anything helpful).

I am not looking for any perl/python answer, I really need bash :)

Thank you!

Comment: I'm going to hold off on marking this as a dupe because my bash knowledge is not up to the task of evaluating the usefulness of the answers and I don't have access to a system to test on right now but I think this is what you need:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380817/best-way-to-simulate-group-by-from-bash

Comment: bash is stringly-typed so there isn't that same object-oriented feel that `Group-Object` has; you're always just manipulating strings.

Comment: @EBGreen - Terrific, thanks! I think the solution proposed on that other thread: grep -ioh "facebook\|xing\|linkedin\|googleplus" access-log.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -n

is exactly what I am looking for! thanks!