# UNIX group by two values

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, grep

I have a file with the following lines (values are separated by ";"):

```
dev_name;dev_type;soft
name1;ASR1;11.1
name2;ASR1;12.2
name3;ASR1;11.1
name4;ASR3;15.1
```

I know how to group them by one value, like count of all ASRx, but how can I group it by two values, as for example:

```
ASR1
    *11.1 - 2
    *12.2 - 1
ASR3 
    *15.1 - 1
```

Comment: Insert the csv as a table in a DB, the use some SQL with a "group by" clause :D

Comment: @funkyjelly There's also the [`q` command](http://harelba.github.io/q/).

Comment: @Socowi Agreed, but might not be available/installed (not that a DB would be more easily available though!)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2613073/2908724

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Your task now is to find out how the following works: `sed '1d;s/^[^;]*;//' file.csv | sort | uniq -c | awk -F ' +|;' '{if(x==$3) {printf("\t*%s - %s\n",$4,$2)} else {x=$3;printf("%s\n\t*%s - %s\n",$3,$4,$2)}}'`

Comment: I wrote a simple solution, but as Cyrus points out this is a help site, not a "please do this for me" site. Please see [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) for how to best ask questions that get helpful responses quickly. Post your attempt, and we will offer suggestions and alternatives.

Comment: @Cyrus, that sample miscounts for me - gives `*11.1 - 1`.

Comment: @PaulHodges: Strange. I use GNU sed, uniq from coreutils and GNU awk.

Comment: @PaulHodges I'm guessing you forgot to include the header line in the input file since [your posted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482059/1745001) relies on there not being a header line.

Comment: Wow. I totally botched that, lol... Thanks, Ed. Will look at fixing it in a while just because I can't leave it broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=";"; OFS=" - " }
NR==1 { next }
$2 != prev { prt(); prev=$2 }
{ cnt[$3]++ }
END { prt() }

function prt(   soft) {
    if ( prev != "" ) {
        print prev
        for (soft in cnt) {
            print "    *" soft, cnt[soft]
        }
        delete cnt
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
ASR1
    *11.1 - 2
    *12.2 - 1
ASR3
    *15.1 - 1
```

Or if you like pipes....

```
$ tail +2 file | cut -d';' -f2- | sort | uniq -c |
    awk -F'[ ;]+' '{print ($3!=prev ? $3 ORS : "") "    *" $4 " - " $2; prev=$3}'
ASR1
    *11.1 - 2
    *12.2 - 1
ASR3
    *15.1 - 1
```

Answer (score 1):

another `awk`

```
$ awk -F';' 'NR>1 {a[$2]; b[$3]; c[$2,$3]++} 
             END  {for(k in a) {print k; 
                                for(p in b) 
                                   if(c[k,p]) print "\t*"p,"-",c[k,p]}}' file
ASR1
        *11.1 - 2
        *12.2 - 1
ASR3
        *15.1 - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to encourage lazy questions, but I wrote a solution, and I'm sure someone can point out improvements. I love posting answers on this site because I learn so much. :)

One binary subcall to `sort`, otherwise all built-in processing. That means using `read`, which is slow. If your file is large, I'd recommend rewriting the loop in `awk` or `perl`, but this will get the job done.

```
sed 1d groups |                        # strip the header
  sort -t';' -k2,3 > group.srt         # pre-sort to collect groupings
declare -i ctr=0                       # initialize integer record counter
IFS=';' read x lastA lastB < group.srt # priming read for comparators
printf "$lastA\n\t*$lastB - "          # priming print (assumes at least one record)
while IFS=';' read x a b               # loop through the file
do if [[ "$lastA" < "$a" ]]            # on every MAJOR change
   then printf "$ctr\n$a\n\t*$b - "    # print total, new MAJOR header and MINOR header
        lastA="$a"                     # update the MAJOR comparator
        lastB="$b"                     # update the MINOR comparator
        ctr=1                          # reset the counter
   elif [[ "$lastB" < "$b" ]]          # on every MINOR change
   then printf "$ctr\n\t*$b - "        # print total and MINOR header
        ctr=1                          # reset the counter
   else (( ctr++ ))                    # otherwise increment
   fi
done < group.srt                       # feed read from sorted file
printf "$ctr\n"                        # print final group total at EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
awk -F ';' '
   NR==1{next}
   {aRaw[$2"-"$3]++}
   END {
      asorti( aRaw, aVal)
      for( Val in aVal) {
         split( aVal [Val], aTmp, /-/ )
         if ( aTmp[1] != Last ) { Last = aTmp[1]; print Last }
         print "   " aTmp[2] " " aRaw[ aVal[ Val] ]
         }
      }
   ' YourFile
```

key here is to use 2 field in a array. The END part is more difficult to present the value than the content itself

Comment: You should mention it requires GNU awk for `asorti()`.

Comment: `$2"-"$3` assumed safe chars are risky.  You may perhaps assume `FS` but not any other.

Comment: @karakfa  did'nt catch the point, your assume it in your solution and not in mine ? could you give a sample where it doesn't work on such a input file ?

Comment: @EdMorton as often, good remark about limitation of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl

```
$ cat bykub.txt
dev_name;dev_type;soft
name1;ASR1;11.1
name2;ASR1;12.2
name3;ASR1;11.1
name4;ASR3;15.1
$ perl -F";" -lane ' $kv{$F[1]}{$F[2]}++ if $.>1;END { while(($x,$y) = each(%kv)) { print $x;while(($p,$q) = each(%$y)){ print "\t\*$p - $q" }}}' bykub.txt
ASR1
        *11.1 - 2
        *12.2 - 1
ASR3
        *15.1 - 1
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet Another Solution, this one using the always useful [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) to count the groups:

```
$ datamash -t ';' --header-in -sg 2,3 count 3 < input.txt |
   awk -F';' '$1 != curr { curr = $1; print $1 } { print "\t*" $2 " - " $3 }' 
ASR1
    *11.1 - 2
    *12.2 - 1
ASR3
    *15.1 - 1
```